What is the word for (style of) answering a question/problem with a question to "deflect" answering the original question back?
See also: Is there a word for answering a question with a question?
Looking specifically for the type of question, style or technique that shifts the responsibility for finding the solution for the proposed problem or question to the original "asker" and thereby invalidating or not addressing the original question. This can be genuine as a form of stasis and according to Socratic method but I am specifically looking for the ingenuine use of this type of question/technique to avoid answering. Often used against "non-experts" that make an observation and are not inherently responsible for "fixing" the addressed problem or question.
Simplified example of an interaction:

Person a: I think there is a problem with x


Person b: do you have a proposal for a solution?

Thus not answering the question / addressing the problem and finding the solution by shifting the incentive back to person a.
Examples for person a: citizen, employee, customer
Examples for person b: policy maker, manager, helpdesk/programmer
In before asking what I think:

Type of ad hominem (what kind?)
Deflection (can't find any sources that back up that this is a thing)
Rhetorical question (does not seem to fit)


Person A didn't ask a question, they made a statement.

"Deflection" seems like a reasonable term for what you're describing, although the example you gave is poor.

A better form of this might be "A: What is X? B: Why do you want to know?"
